# Java: Cannot redefine class during instrumentation on attach

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I have a simple application that creates and uses instances of `ToChange` class in a loop:

```
public class ToChange {
  private int i;
  public ToChange(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

```
public class MyApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("pid = " + ProcessHandle.current().pid());
    int i = 0;
    // This is an instance for the whole application lifecycle
    var wholeAppInstance = new ToChange(0);

    while (true) {
      // Use the wholeAppInstance first
      wholeAppInstance.print();

      // Create and use a new instance in each loop
      new ToChange(++i).print();

      System.out.println("------------");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While the application runs, there are such lines in the console:

```
0
1
------------
0
2
------------
0
3
------------
```

I also have an `attach` application that loads an agent and attaches it to a running JVM.
It takes two arguments, the first is the `pid` of a the running JVM process and the second is the path of the agent that will be attached:

```
// The main class of the attach application
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException, AgentLoadException, AgentInitializationException {
    String processId = args[0];
    String agentJar = args[1];
    VirtualMachine virtualMachine = VirtualMachine.attach(processId);
    try {
      virtualMachine.loadAgent(agentJar);
    } catch (Exception error) {
      error.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      virtualMachine.detach();
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I have the agent, which redefines the `ToChange` class:

```
public class MyAgentMain {
  public static void agentmain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Agent mark 1");
    Class<?> toChange = Class.forName("org.abc.security.attach.application.ToChange");

    System.out.println("Agent mark 2");
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (InputStream input = MyAgentMain
            .class
            .getResourceAsStream("/org/abc/security/attach/application/ToChange.class")) {
      System.out.println("input reference: " + input);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int length;
      while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
      System.out.println("Agent mark 3");
    } catch (Exception error) {
      error.printStackTrace();
    }

    instrumentation.redefineClasses(new ClassDefinition(toChange, output.toByteArray()));
    System.out.println("Agent mark 4");
  }
}
```

The MANIFEST.MF of the agent contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Agent-Class: org.abc.security.attach.agent.MyAgentMain
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
```

And the `ToChange` class is changed to the following:

```
public class ToChange {
  private int i;

  public ToChange(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println("Changed:" + this.i);
  }
}
```

I execute the attach application, passing the pid of the running `MyApplication` and the agent location:

`java --add-modules jdk.attach -jar attach-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $PID agent-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I see in the `MyApplication` console the `println`s produced by the agent and there are no errors neither in the `MyApplication` console, nor in the agent console.

However, after the agent completes, I still see the same output in `MyApplication`:

```
------------
0
7
------------
Agent mark 1
Agent mark 2
input reference: java.io.BufferedInputStream@540e6237
Agent mark 3
Agent mark 4
0
8
------------
0
9
------------
```

I would expect that since there are no errors, the instrumentation succeeds, the `ChangeTo` class gets redefined and the `println`s are different.
However, this is not the case...

What I am doing (or expecting) wrong?

---

**EDITED to answer my question**

@johannes-kuhn 's reply gave me the idea to try changing the redefined class location in the agent, in order not to be under the same path with the original.

It seems that the "resources" of the final, instrumented `MyApplication` remained unchanged, because the redefined class had the same path in the resources with the old one. Changing the location of the ToChange class in the agent resources, did the trick!

For clarity, here is the working `MyAgentMain`:

```
public class MyAgentMain {
  public static void agentmain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Agent mark 1");
    Class<?> license = Class.forName("org.abc.security.attach.application.ToChange");

    System.out.println("Agent mark 2");
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (InputStream input = MyAgentMain
            .class
            .getResourceAsStream("/ToChange.class")) { // THE NON-WORKING VERSION HAD /org/abc/security/attach/application/ToChange.class
      System.out.println("input reference: " + input);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int length;
      while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
      System.out.println("Agent mark 3");
    } catch (Exception error) {
      error.printStackTrace();
    }

    instrumentation.redefineClasses(new ClassDefinition(license, output.toByteArray()));
    System.out.println("Agent mark 4");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading the right bytecode? A java agent is always loaded with the system class loader, and the system class loader search path is **appended** with the agent jar file. My guess is that `MyAgentMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/abc/security/attach/application/ToChange.class")` returns the original bytecode.

Comment: A quick way to test this is to look at the length of the byte array and the file sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have the compiled class in the `agent` project resources (I use maven). When I open the class with a decompiler, I see indeed that the println is `System.out.println("Changed:" + this.i);`

Comment: You know, you can load any class as resource, even if the class is not in the resource directory. Try to rename the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Johannes Kuhn. Your reply gave me the idea to try changing the redefined class location, in order not to be under the same path with the original. It seems that the "resources" of the final, instrumented `MyApplication` remained unchanged, since the redefined class had the same path with the old one. Changing the location of the `ToChange` class in the resources, did the trick!

Comment: Instead of editing your question to provide the answer, you can post an answer on your question, then mark it as accepted (after 2 days) so people can see clearly that your problem is solved.

Comment: Also a few general notes about your program: Since Java 9, there is [`InputStream.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes%28%29). For the MCVE, you already declared that it `throws Exception` - you could remove the catch.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I will write an answer, once I get to it. OP confirmed my suspicion, so I now have enough information to write one.

Comment: Is it better to remove my edit and wait for @johannes-kuhn answer? Apologizes... This is my first question.

Comment: You could, or both of you could post answers. But you can only mark one answer as accepted. I would probably accept Johannes' answer once he posts it to thank him for helping you. But nothing stops you from posting your own answer in the meantime, which could be useful if it will take Johannes a while to post his.

Comment: I have a question: This all looks nice in theory, but IMO attaching to a running process with the target class already loaded, it should be impossible to redefine the target class because redefinition only works during class loading. The only practical way I see for instrumenting an already loaded class is retransformation with all its limitations regarding not changing class structure. Or are you actually attaching to the other JVM before the target class has been loaded? @Aska, can you please comment on this?

Comment: OK, I tried this by myself and I am half right and half wrong: You can call `redefine` on a loaded class if (and only if) there are no structural changes inside the class. Then the JVM **implicitly performs a retransformation.** In your case it works because you do not add/remove any fields or methods and do not change method signatures. You only change a method body, which is compatible with retransformation, so the JVM does not mind.

Comment: For an incompatible change however, redefinition would fail and the attacher JVM would throw `AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize`. In the target JVM, the program would continue to run but you would see `Exception in thread "Attach Listener" ...InvocationTargetException` and further down the stack trace `NoClassDefFoundError: class names don't match` (rather misleading because class names are not the problem here) in combination with the log message `Agent failed to start!`.

Comment: @kriegaex, you are right. AFAIK, the new class that is replacing a loaded one **must** define the exact same fields, methods and modifiers. Otherwise, an UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown. For example, if you try to remove a method, you will see `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to delete a method`.

Comment: BTW, there was some work attempting to resolve the above limitation but [the JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/159) is in closed/withdrawn state.

Comment: To be clear, I know all the requirements. My surprise was only that for an already loaded class you don't need to call `retransform` like I thought and always do to make sure the intent is clear, but that `redefine` also works and silently switches to retransformation. I thought that the JVM would refuse a redefine call on a loaded class.

Comment: @kriegaex it seems, you have a wrong understanding of what “redefine” does. It is *only* applicable to already loaded classes, otherwise, it wouldn’t be a **re**define operation (and no, it does not do a retransform). When you want to do load-time transformation only, you don’t need to call redefine at all, just registering the transformer is enough.

Comment: @Holger, you are right. For a moment I was mislead by the old typo in [`Instrumentation.addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#addTransformer(java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer,%20boolean)) which existed at least since Java 6 and still is in the Javadoc in Java 15. Quote: "The transformer is called when classes are loaded, when they are redefined." This can be read as "when they are loaded, i.e. redefined."

Comment: In reality, the period does not signify the end of a sentence, though, it is just a typo and ought to be removed, because afterwards comes a lower-case "and" which is just continuing an enumeration of cases: "is called when classes are loaded, when they are redefined and if canRetransform is true, when they are retransformed." If there is no period after "redefined", it becomes clear.

Comment: Of course, if you also read the Javadoc for `redefineClasses(ClassDefinition...)` and `retransformClasses(Class<?>...)` everything becomes clearer in context, but reading what I quoted in isolation is quite misleading. This is a wonderful example of why punctuation matters.  So basically, redefinition and retransformation are both subject to the same restrictions, the main difference is that redefinition works without a reference to existing class bytes, just providing its own bytes, and retransformation takes an existing class definition as its input.

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy explanation, I want to explain how I ever ended up thinking redefinition - despite the prefix "re" - would be executed during class-loading and could in that case do any kind of change to a class. I only ever used retransformation in all my previous agents because I never had a case in which I did not operate on existing byte code. And this damn period in that `addTransformer` Javadoc made me misinterpret that sentence. So thank you, @Holger, for correcting my false statement based on this misconception. I am always happy to learn.

Comment: @kriegaex that’s indeed a bad documentation. There’s no need for such a sentence structure at all. Note further that the subsequent sentence “*See ClassFileTransformer.transform for the order of transform calls*” of JDK 6 got rewritten to “*ClassFileTransformer defines the order of transform calls*” in [JDK 15](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#addTransformer(java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer,boolean)) That’s more than misleading, it reaches the level of being just wrong.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn do you plan to provide an answer for this, or should I go on and provide one?